Creating a frequency schedule that updates dynamically based on start date & cadence
I'm looking to create a frequency schedule that highlights when each activity should be performed throughout the year based on the dropdown cadence (daily, monthly, quarterly, semi-annually) and the start date. So if it's daily, it should repeat on every day after the start date. If monthly, every month after the start date and so on.
The attached image is what the desired result would be.
enter image description here
I can figure out the daily easily enough using the rept & split function but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to skip say 30/31 cells for the monthly and more for the quarterly and semi-annually based on the dynamic cadence & start date.
Sample sheet access https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-luCbmldWuGBEJJBYtHnBlFs60Ol5h7OIdNHdZKs3wM/edit?usp=sharing

You need to find a function that returns the date, given the start date and the number of days from the start date.  No idea what that would be in "google-sheets", but in C++ it is in std::chrono.  Recommend: stop mucking around in the cloud and write an application in your favorite coding language.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

I've added a sample sheet with the desired results.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,index(match(,0/(A:A<>""))),map(A5:index(A:A,Σ),B5:index(B:B,Σ),lambda(a,b,if(or(a="",b=""),,map(C3:3,lambda(c,let(Λ,max(C3:3),
 if(a="Daily",if(vlookup(c,sequence(Λ-b+1,1,b),1,),C1),
 if(ifna(vlookup(c,sort(edate(b,sequence(datedif(b,Λ,"m")+1,1,0,switch(a,"Monthly",1,"Quarterly",3,"Semi-Annually",6)))),1,)),C1,)))))))))



@ravenspoint I agree that rockinfreakshow's code could be pretty-printed to make it easier on the eye, but see nothing wrong with the logic. Spreadsheet formula languages constitute functional programming that differs from the imperative and object-oriented models. See Lambda calculus.

alternative:
=INDEX(BYROW(A5:INDEX(A:A, MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A<>""))), 
 LAMBDA(a, LET(b, OFFSET(a,,1), d, C3:3, IF(((a="Daily")*(b<=d))+
 ISNUMBER(MATCH(d, EDATE(b, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(MIN(d), MAX(d), "M"),, 
 SWITCH(a, "Monthly", 1, "Quarterly", 3, "Semi-Annually", 6))), )), C1, )))))


spreadsheet demo

bonus...
fill with dates from date x till last column:
=SEQUENCE(1, COLUMNS(C3:3), "2024-01-01")

fill with dates from date x to date y:
=SEQUENCE(1, ABS("2024-01-01"-"2024-12-31")+1, "2024-01-01")

fill day names:
=INDEX(IF(C3:3="",,TEXT(C3:3, "ddd")))


This worked wonderfully, but I'm now having the issue of having to add in a weekly category (column A). The EDATE function doesn't seem to work with weekly as far as I can tell. I tried using just DAYS and adjusting the SWITCH parameters, but was having an issue tying that with the Start Date (column B) so I'm not sure what I missed. Any suggestions?
